# What is this microwave filter thing?

Tags: kitchens, vent, microwave-oven

During the process of remodeling my kitchen, I removed the Over-the-range Microwave but when I put back in, I saw this piece

[image]

I frankly cannot fit it anywhere, not in the bottom or on top at the vent

Here is the bottom

[image]

I had another microwave like this and never recalled a piece like that.

Is this from microwave or something else?

**UPDATE 1**

The microwave is **ge model jvm3160rf3ss**

Comment: What do you mean "you saw this piece" ?   You did not see it when you took out the microwave.   where did you find it?    not enough info.

Comment: I removed the microwave and don't remember if that piece is from the microwave itself or from somewhere that I just happened to lay next to the microwave.

Comment: What model is your microwave? Does it vent into the room or to an outside exhaust pipe?

Comment: I liked isherwood's answer that was deleted I see the grids in the bottom but this may have been a trap on this or the one prior that was removed.

Comment: That looks too clean to have been in use ...

Comment: get a parts catalog for your microwave and look for it ...... that looks like the exhaust filter

Comment: Yes it is GE. The model is ge model jvm3160rf3ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an exhaust filter, primarily intended for if the stove fan exhausts back into the kitchen instead of to outside the house.

This filter has charcoal inside to absorb odors so they don't get recirculated through the kitchen.

For your GE model jvm3160rf3ss, its part number is [WB02X11550](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/spec/WB02X11550). The product page there has looks to videos that show where this part goes and how to replace it.